# Configuring riak-ruby to work with docker cluster

Tags: ruby, docker, riak

I installed a riak cluster with the following: http://basho.com/posts/technical/riak-quick-start-with-docker/

When trying the very basic commands on http://basho.github.io/riak-ruby-client/ the client hangs in `a.store`

I ran my dockers in a VM in virtualbox which its ip is 192.168.99.101

the riak cluster containers are

```
5c896346de61        hectcastro/riak     "/sbin/my_init --quie"   46 seconds ago       Up 44 seconds       0.0.0.0:32777->8087/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32776->8098/tcp   riak05
f32b9af999cf        hectcastro/riak     "/sbin/my_init --quie"   50 seconds ago       Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:32775->8087/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32774->8098/tcp   riak04
891e5e63a4b2        hectcastro/riak     "/sbin/my_init --quie"   About a minute ago   Up 58 seconds       0.0.0.0:32773->8087/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32772->8098/tcp   riak03
65848cd3e218        hectcastro/riak     "/sbin/my_init --quie"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32771->8087/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->8098/tcp   riak02
39ad8ded2477        hectcastro/riak     "/sbin/my_init --quie"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32769->8087/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->8098/tcp   riak01
```

I've set the client in ruby to

```
client = Riak::Client.new(pb_port: 32770, host: "192.168.99.101")
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Can you connect using `netcat` or some other tool to port `32770` from the same environment in which you're running the Ruby client?

Does the client throw any errors after a period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your container container info,

```
0.0.0.0:32771->8087/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->8098/tcp
```

8098 is the default HTTP port, 8087 is the default protocol buffers port.
Unless you have changed the ports in your Riak config, you probably need to use 32771 as the pb_port.

Comment: ah, I thought I need the default port. Thanks!